# Proofs my Contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to solve the following problem by prooving using Contradiction. The problem is:

Show that for any nonnegative real numbers $a$ and $b$ we have: $\frac {a+b}2 ≥ \sqrt {ab}$

(Sadly, i dont even know where to start for this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always to start a proof by contradiction you should assume the negation of the desired result and try to find a contradiction. So let assume that there's $a,b\in\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ s.t.
$$\frac{a+b}2<\sqrt{ab}\iff a+b<2\sqrt{ab}$$
so by squaring and developing we find
$$a^2+b^2+2ab<4ab\iff a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2<0\;\text{which's a contradiction}$$
we conclude that the hypothesis is wrong and then its negation: 
$$\forall a,b\in\Bbb R_{\ge0},\quad \frac{a+b}2\ge\sqrt{ab}$$
is true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider $$\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right)^2$$

This is also known as the [arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).